# Snyk complains about fsevents missing from package-lock, but fsevents is not a requirement and snyk ignores --strict-out-of-sync=false

Tags: node.js, npm, snyk

Cannot run **snyk** on any of my projects today, getting the same error everywhere.

`snyk test --strict-out-of-sync=false` results in:

> *Dependency fsevents was not found in package-lock.json. Your package.json and package-lock.json are probably out of sync. Please run "npm install" and try again.*

`npm install` and `npm i --package-lock-only` do nothing.

**FSEvents** is not even a requirement in `package.json`

relevant sections of the `package.json`:

```json
      "dependencies": {
        "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "csurf": "^1.11.0",
        "debug": "~4.3.1",
        "express": "~4.17.1",
        "express-handlebars": "^5.3.0",
        "express-rate-limit": "^5.2.6",
        "helmet": "^4.4.1",
        "morgan": "~1.10.0",
        "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
        "node-cron": "^3.0.0",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
        "nodemailer": "^6.5.0",
        "redis": "^3.1.0",
        "sequelize": "^6.6.2",
        "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2",
        "winston": "^3.3.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "app-root-path": "^3.0.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "chai": "^4.3.4",
        "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
        "eslint": "^7.23.0",
        "express-openapi-validate": "^0.5.1",
        "js-yaml": "^4.0.0",
        "jsdoc": "^3.6.6",
        "mocha": "^8.3.2",
        "nyc": "^15.1.0",
        "openapi-types": "^7.2.3",
        "sinon": "^10.0.0",
        "snyk": "^1.526.0",
        "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.1.0",
        "winston-syslog": "^2.4.4"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I hope you've already solved this but found this thread with the same issue so posting if someone finds it later.

[`fsevents`](https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents) is probably a transitive dependency for some of your other dependencies, check the `package-lock.json` for which one. It is a MacOS (darwin) only package to get access to file system events.

I got it working by running

```
npm upgrade
```

before running **snyk** again.

Answer (score 1):

**fsevents** is used inside of jest or other testing library.
*npm upgrade* will update all outdated libraries. This approach is not recommended, if you do not want to update all the libraries you use. Instead of that, **just update testing libraries you use** and the issue will be gone.

Comment: May also need to `delete package-lock.json` file and run `npm install` like in my case.

Comment: If you update the specific library, it will update the package-lock.json file too